# ES query ignoring time range filter

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have mimicked how kibana does a query search and have come up with the below query. Basically I'm looking for the lat 6 days of data (including those days where there is no data, since I need to feed it to a graph). But the returned buckets is giving me more than just those days. I woul like to understand where I'm going wring with this.

```
{
     "version": true,
     "size": 0,
     "sort": [
         {
             "@timestamp": {
                 "order": "desc",
                 "unmapped_type": "boolean"
             }
         }
     ],
     "_source": {
         "excludes": []
     },
     "aggs": {
         "target_traffic": {
             "date_histogram": {
                 "field": "@timestamp",
                 "interval": "1d",
                 "time_zone": "Asia/Kolkata",
                 "min_doc_count": 0,
                 "extended_bounds": {
                     "min": "now-6d/d",
                     "max": "now"
                 }
             },
             "aggs": {
                 "days_filter": {
                     "filter": {
                         "range": {
                             "@timestamp": {
                                 "gt": "now-6d",
                                 "lte": "now"
                             }

                         }
                     },
                     "aggs": {
                         "in_bytes": {
                             "sum": {
                                 "field": "netflow.in_bytes"
                             }
                         },
                         "out_bytes": {
                             "sum": {
                                 "field": "netflow.out_bytes"
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     },
     "stored_fields": [
         "*"
     ],
     "script_fields": {},
     "docvalue_fields": [
         "@timestamp",
         "netflow.first_switched",
         "netflow.last_switched"
     ],
     "query": {
         "bool": {
             "must": [
                 {
                     "query_string": {
                         "query": "( flow.src_addr: (  \"10.5.5.1\" OR \"10.5.5.2\" ) OR flow.dst_addr: (  \"10.5.5.1\" OR \"10.5.5.2\" ) ) AND flow.traffic_locality: \"private\"",
                         "analyze_wildcard": true,
                         "default_field": "*"
                     }
                 }
             ]
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: why don't you put your `range` in the query section? it doesn't make much sense to put it where you put it.

Comment: @Val - Thanks for the heads up. You are correct. I've put the range into the query and it appears to be behaving the way I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the `range` filter inside your aggregation section without any date range in your query, what is going to happen is that your aggregations will run on all your data and metrics will be bucketed by day over all your data.

The `range` query on `@timestamp` should be moved inside the `query` section so as to compute aggregations only on the data you want, i.e. the last 6 days.